# Not include records from within a select query matching a criteria

Tags: sql-server

I have a query in sql server that is displaying a few records that i DONT want. The relation of the fields goes as follows:

A ClientID can have multiple Workloads (WorkloadIDs) but not the other way round (one-to-many).
Each WorkloadID has a unit assigned to it.
Each WorkloadID has a DWLD (date) assigned to it.
Multiple WorkloadIDs can have the same ClientID, DWLD and Unit.

Here is the query:

```
select 
w.WorkloadID,
w.ClientID,
w.Unit,
w.DWLD

        from 
        Workload as w
        left JOIN Clients as cli
        ON w.ClientID = cli.ClientID

    where

        w.DWLD >= @start AND w.DWLD < @enddate
        and w.IsDeleted <> 1
```

i want it to not display only 1 record out of a few number of records available which have the same ClientID AND the same Unit AND the same DWLD. i have tried self joining the table, using the having clause and not exists clause but havent got the right result.

thanks!

[Data displayed from the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3fiI.png)

[Source Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LShC.png)

Comment: Instead of a word problem, could you show sample data and desired results?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/C3fiI.png

Comment: The desired results do not make sense to me. You want to exclude the rows that are red? Why do we keep WorkloadID 108 and 131, but reject 130? Are there rows from the source tables that aren't included in your screen shot? It's really difficult to determine a query to produce results in a screen shot of a spreadsheet without knowing what the source data looks like. Could you please provide tabular sample data and tabular results in the question?

Comment: as im new here, im having a little trouble uploading the table as it is. if you could let me know how, that would be very much helpful. i am attaching another image to this as well having the whole table.

as i looked through your question, i noticed something that is not mentioned in my requirement. there is another clause that i should be looking at. WorkloadID 131 and 130 have the same WorkLoadFor (EmployeeID) field.  so the top 3 conditions goes along with both records who have the same WorkLoadFor comes into play as well.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8LShC.png

i need at least 10 reputation to post images that is why i cant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query. When you are not retrieving records from the `clients` table, no need to join that.

```
select w.WorkloadID, w.ClientID, w.Unit, w.DWLD
from Workload as w
where w.DWLD BETWEEN @start AND  @enddate
and w.IsDeleted <> 1 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Workload 
WEHRE ClientId = w.clientid 
and unit = w.unit and dwld = w.dwld 
and workloadid < w.workloadid 
and DWLD BETWEEN @start AND  @enddate 
AND IsDeleted <> 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values in column DWLD differ by hours / minutes and you want them grouped by days use cast(cast( DWLD as float) as int)

```
select 
max(w.WorkloadID) as WorkloadID,
w.ClientID,
w.Unit,
w.DWLD

        from 
        Workload as w
        left JOIN Clients as cli
        ON w.ClientID = cli.ClientID

    where

        w.DWLD >= @start AND w.DWLD < @enddate
        and w.IsDeleted <> 1

group by w.ClientID,
w.Unit,
w.DWLD
```